# Faster RCNN using Tensorflow object detectionn API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I trained a faster RCNN model (faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco_2018_01_28/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco) using Tensorflow 1.x version. This is the result on Tensorboard
[Tensorboard loss value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQtlb.png)

I stopped training after about 400K steps.
Testing it on test dataset, I found that it outputs multiple bounding boxes on the same object, sometimes of the same class, sometimes of different classes. These are some examples :
[first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5kTI.png)

[second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Gyh.png)

How can I force it to draw one bounding box with the highest score nad should I train it more ?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the score threshold in your inference code. It can be seen in your first example that there are 2 bounding boxes, if your threshold was above 80 percent, you would have got only one.

Another solution would be to apply
Non-maximum Suppression (NMS) technique. You can find the code in [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/).

> Non Maximum Suppression (NMS) is a technique used in many computer vision algorithms. It is a class of algorithms to select one entity (e.g. bounding boxes) out of many overlapping entities.